# If condition with single and (&)

Tags: c++

We all know && (double and) for and condition.
for single and What happen internally how condition gets executed.

```
 if(true & bSuccess)
{
}
```

Comment: What type is `bSuccess`?

Comment: Do you know what `&` does? The expression gets evaluated and implicitly converted to `bool`.

Comment: bSuccess is of type bool

Comment: @BenVoigt: a typical example of a codebase using System Hungarian Notation :(

Comment: It's simple as if the expression gives a positive result for the AND operation! I hope bFlag is of type bool

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
true & bSuccess
```

in this expression both operands are promoted to `int` and then `&` is evaluated. If bSuccess is true you will get `1 & 1` which is `1` (or `true`). If bSuccess is false you'll get `1 & 0` which is `0` (or `false`)

So, in case of boolean values `&&` and `&` will always yield the same result, but they are not totally equivalent in that `&` will always evaluate both its arguments and `&&` will not evaluate its second argument if the first one is false.

Example:

```
bool f() { std::cout << "f"; return false; }
bool g() { std::cout << "g"; return true; }

int main()
{
    f() && g(); //prints f. Yields false
    f() & g();  //prints fg or gf (unspecified). Yields 0 (false)
}
```

Comment: @sandip123: it's equivalent to `if (bSuccess)`, just slightly more confusing (assuming `bSuccess` is a variable of type `bool`).

Comment: Bitwise and and logical and are *not* the same.

Answer (score 8):

In your case since bSuccess is bool then

`if(true & bSuccess)` is *exactly* the same as `if(true && bSuccess)`

However had you used this :

```
short i = 3;
short k = 1;
```

`if(i & k)` the result will be true :

```
0000 0000 0000 0011 
                    &
0000 0000 0000 0001
-------------------
0000 0000 0000 0001 true
```

& operates on individual bits and here bit 1 is the same in both case so you have true as a result.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Don't teach this way; people tend to forget about the "in your case" and just remember the "is exactly the same" part.

Comment: @Griwes I changed the font :)