# If with single and statement in c

Tags: if-statement

What is this code doing?

if( x & y) 
do something

if( x || !y) 
do something

I am familiar with all basic functions of if statements (<, >, ==, !=)

Comment: Just google *logical operators*.

Comment: A quick google search led me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167249/if-condition-with-single-and). Also, the other one is an "OR" statement (!y) is well "not y"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&` (bitwise and) is a [bitwise operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm). You can see some examples at the link there.

Specifically, `&` and will take the binary representation of `x` and `y`, compare the bits, and return the result. The link above has the following example:

> `(A & B) = 12, i.e., 0000 1100`

`||` (or) and `!` (not) are [logical operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm). This second line is saying "if `x` is true, OR if NOT `y` is true, do something".